# How to pass the ButtonListener to DialogFragment with Jetpack Navigation

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a MessageDialog which extends DialogFragment.It has a textView and two buttons(OK and Cancel).I want to use Jetpack Navigation for showing or hideing the dialog.Now i have a question,how to pass the buttonListener to the Dialog with Navigation.

Comment: Before you post, Summarize the problem and Provide details.

Comment: Please put your code here and define your problems properly